# How to disable hot tracking UI feature in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, themes, user-interface, tree-view

Is it possible to disable hot tracking in tree- and listview controls in Windows 7? I guess this is related to the Aero theme, but I don't want to switch to Classic. I would like to have Aero without hot tracking. Is it possible?

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you define hot tracking? Do you mean this.....http://superuser.com/questions/61821/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-highlighted-file-color-in-windows-7

Comment: I found this but don't understand this type of registry editing....http://www.silisoftware.com/tools/tweakui.php

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. I want to have classic selection style in Windows explorer. Without selection rectangle on mouse hovering and without full line selection.

Comment: Tried the mentioned registry setting, but it disabled hot tracking only in tree view.

Comment: You may have to use a 3rd party file explorer like classic shell

Comment: Added animated GIF from [How to disable hot tracking UI feature in Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/598064/how-to-disable-hot-tracking-ui-feature-in-windows-8) for those who don't know what hot tracking is.

Comment: @Karan where is  "all rights reserved " ?  :-)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Since all our contributions here are licensed as per Creative Commons anyway, guess you already gave implicit permission when you posted the image. :)