# How to disable hot tracking UI feature in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, themes, user-interface

When I click on a row it highlights the line with blue background (regular behaviour), but when I mouseover other rows it highlights them too.

How can I disable this?

[image: 1]

Comment: Its not possible to disable this feature.

Comment: "not possible" is a very dangerous saying in computer world... (:-))

Comment: I challenge somebody to prove me wrong.

Comment: with the right amount of programming/reverse engineering skills and time this is definitely possible. Major problem is finding someone willing to spend time on it..

Comment: Related: [How to disable hot tracking UI feature in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/480789/how-to-disable-hot-tracking-ui-feature-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in Windows settings that support disabling that highlight. It can be achieved, but only by modifying the Windows theme. This will require a Windows [resource editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_%28Windows%29#Resource_software) and a patch to allow custom themes to be applied (for example, UltraUXThemePatcher). You will need to open the .msstyles file of the theme with the resource editor, and replace the existing image with a transparent image. The theme images are under the "IMAGE" or "IMG" entry under the resource editor. The number of the actual image to replace will depend on the underlying theme and the windows version.
For Windows 8.1, with the built-in aero theme, the image number is #605 for the File Explorer mouse-over highlight.

An easier alternative to using a resource editor, is using a theme making program such as Windows Style Builder. This is however a paid application, and I'm not sure how good the Windows 8 support is.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser, we seek to have the main details on how to solve a problem in the answer and not just in a (potentially broken in the future) link. It would be great if you could edit your answer to provide a summary of the solution.

Comment: Okay, done that.