# Windows 10 - Is it possible to change the higlight color of file explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, colors

The light blue color used to highlight files is barely visible. On a bright screen it is very difficult to tell the selected file on first look. [image]

[This thread is about Windows 7 and not working for me](https://superuser.com/questions/61821/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-highlighted-file-color-on-windows-7)